# Using linq to query a collection, grouping and summing certain items

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

For some reason I cannot get the correct vb.net syntax (visual studio 2010) for a Linq statement that will do the following. Simplest and most straight forward code would be appreciated.

Here is the problem:

I have a collection of approximately 45,000 objects and need to summarize some of the data.

```
Collection name:    DrillableData
Object name:        Ord_Detail
```

Fields of interest:

```
Ord_detail.routeno
```

(Integer – used to identify a route number.  In the whole population of 45,000 items there are only 20 or so route numbers.)

```
Ord_Detail.TotPrice
```

(Double – contains sale $amount)

```
Ord_Detail.ProdQty
```

(Integer – contains sale quantity)

(There are other fields but I am only interested in TotPrice and ProdQty summarized by routeno.)

What I need is to summarize Totprice and ProdQty by routeno.

The result should yield a list of about 20 lines with 3 pieces of data on each line Route #, TotPrice, ProdQty.    Can you give me the Linq code that will query the collection and do this?

So far I have been able to put this together, but, obviously this does not yield what I need.

```
        Dim Thistotal2 As Object = (From Ord_detail In DrillableDetails
                       Group Ord_detail By Ord_detail.routeno _
                       Into Group _
                       Select totprice = Group.Sum(Function(ord_detail) ord_detail.totprice))


        For Each totprice In Thistotal2
            Total = totprice
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
    Dim TotalsByRoute = From Order_Detail In DrillableDetails
                        Order By Order_Detail.routeno
                        Group Order_Detail By Order_Detail.routeno
                        Into Route = Group
                        Select New With {
                            .RouteNumber = routeno,
                            .TotalQty = Route.Sum(Function(x) x.ProdQty),
                            .TotalPrice = Route.Sum(Function(x) x.TotPrice)
                        }
```